# Svelte - Unable to upload image

Tags: typescript, svelte

I am trying to upload an image and send it as a formData. However, during the binding, it is changing from File to string.

Form.svelte

```
<!-- src/components/Form.svelte -->
<script lang="ts">
  import { createEventDispatcher } from 'svelte';
  import Field from "./Field.svelte";
  import type { Video } from '../model/video';
  import { submitForm } from '../lib/api'; 

  const dispatch = createEventDispatcher();

  export let video: Video = {
    name: '',
    description: '',
    ep_count: 0,
    cover_image: undefined
  };


  // export let errors: Record<string, string> = {};
  export let loading = false;
  export let errors: Record<string, { message: string }> = {};
  export let darkMode: boolean;

  $: if (video.cover_image) {

    console.log("video.cover_image");
        console.log(video.cover_image);
        console.log(video.cover_image.size);
    }
  async function handleSubmit() {
    // Validate form fields here, set errors if necessary
    if (!video.name.trim()) {
      errors.name = { message: 'Name is required' };
      return;
    }

    console.log('Form submitted:', video);

    // Perform form submission if validation passes
    await submitForm(video);
    dispatch('submit');
  }
</script>

<form on:submit|preventDefault={handleSubmit} class="max-w-md mx-auto p-4 bg-{darkMode ? 'gray-800' : 'white'} shadow-md rounded-md form-control">
  

  <Field
    name="cover_image"
    label="Cover Image"
    type="file"
    bind:value={video.cover_image}
    errors={errors} />

  <div class="mt-6 flex justify-center">
    <button
      type="submit"
      class="btn"
      disabled={loading}>
      {loading ? 'Saving...' : 'Save'}
    </button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Field.svelte

```
<!-- src/components/Field.svelte -->

<script lang="ts">
  export let value: any;
  export let label: string;
  export let name: string;
  export let type: string;
  export let errors: Record<string, { message: string }> = {};

  $: hasErrors = errors && errors[name];

  const handleInput = (e: Event) => {
    // Ensure that the event is an input event before accessing the value
    if (e.target instanceof HTMLInputElement) {
      if (type === "number") {
        value = Number(e.target.value);
      } else if (type === "file") {
        const files = e.target.files;
        let file = files && files.length > 0 ? files[0] : null;
        console.log(files);
        console.log("handleInput: ");
        console.log(typeof file);
        console.log("Properties of object:", file?.size);
        
        value = file;
        console.log("Properties of object:", value?.size);

      } else {
        value = e.target.value;
      }
    }
  };
</script>

<div class="mb-4 flex items-center">
  <label for={name} class="text-gray-700 text-sm font-bold mb-2 label">
    {label}
  </label>
  {#if type === "file"}
    <input
      type="file"
      placeholder={label}
      id={name}
      class="file-input w-full max-w-xs"
      bind:value
      on:input={handleInput}
      accept="image/*"
    />
  {:else if type === "checkbox"}
    <input
      type="number"
      placeholder={label}
      id={name}
      class="input input-bordered w-full max-w-xs"
      bind:value
      on:input={handleInput}
    />
  {:else}
    <!-- Default case: render a text input if the type is not 'file' or 'checkbox' -->
    <input
      type="text"
      placeholder={label}
      id={name}
      class="input input-bordered w-full max-w-xs"
      bind:value
      on:input={handleInput}
    />
  {/if}
  {#if hasErrors}
    <p class="text-red-500 text-xs italic mt-1">{errors[name].message}</p>
  {/if}
</div>
<!-- class={`w-full p-2 ${inputClass} border`} -->
```

Video.ts

```
export interface Video {
    name: string;
    description: string;
    cover_image?: File;
    ep_count: number;
}
```

console logs

```
FileList [ File ]
handleInput: 
object 
Properties of object: 88188 
Properties of object: 88188 
video.cover_image 
File { name: "sample_image.png", lastModified: 1703955579385, webkitRelativePath: "", size: 88188, type: "image/png" }
88188 
video.cover_image 
C:\fakepath\sample_image.png 
undefined
```

why is video_cover_image being printed two times and first with file and then as a string, because of that, i am unable to submit the form with the image.